# Can't select whole UV mesh in UV editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]as it is seen in picture, i can't select whole mesh - three squares are not selected. So, as i'm a beginer, i think that is the reason that UV Squares plugin doesn't work. I tried it with another mesh and it worked. what can i do? [image]

Thanks, 
gregork

Comment: Hello :). The whole uv island **is** selected. The grey-ish face is *active face* and those two missing are cutouts for the cup handle.

Comment: Aha:) ok i get it. tnx!  still, have some ideas, why uv square plug in doesn't work in this particular mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inside of your mesh. Either you have a face inside the mesh or they're multiple vertices in one spot. Select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*. Unwrap mesh again. If there is a face inside the mesh, delete it and then unwrap it again.